# Multivariate GARCH(1,1) in R

Tags: r

I use R to estimate a Multivariate GARCH(1,1) model for 4 time series. I tried it with the rmgarch package. Seems like I'm using it wrong but I don't know what my mistake is. First time using.

```
library(quantmod)
library(fBasics)
library(rmgarch)
#load data, time series closing prices, 10 year sample
#DAX 30
getSymbols('^GDAXI', src='yahoo', return.class='ts',from="2005-01-01",    to="2015-01-31")
GDAXI.DE=GDAXI[ , "GDAXI.Close"]
#S&P 500
getSymbols('^GSPC', src='yahoo', return.class='ts',from="2005-01-01", to="2015-01-31")
GSPC=GSPC[ , "GSPC.Close"]
#Credit Suisse Commodity Return Strat I
getSymbols('CRSOX', src='yahoo', return.class='ts',from="2005-01-01", to="2015-01-31")
CRSOX=CRSOX[ , "CRSOX.Close"]
#iShares MSCI Emerging Markets
getSymbols('EEM', src='yahoo', return.class='ts',from="2005-01-01", to="2015-01-31")
EEM=EEM[ , "EEM.Close"]
#calculating log returns of the time series
log_r1=diff(log(GDAXI.DE[39:2575]))
log_r2=diff(log(GSPC))
log_r3=diff(log(CRSOX))
log_r4=diff(log(EEM))
#return vector
r_t=cbind(log_r1, log_r2,log_r3, log_r4)
#specifying and fitting the model
model = multispec(replicate(4, ugarchspec(variance.model = c(1,1))))
model_order = mgarchspec(model, Order = c(1, 1), distribution ='mvnorm')
fit = mgarchfit(model_order, data = r_t, solver = 'solnp',fit.control =    list(eval.se = TRUE))
print(fit.1)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

below you will find a parallel implementation of a multivariate DCC and ADCC Garch models. It is unclear what you are trying to achieve, but I assume you are looking for some kind of correlation between each of the variables. Or at least an uncorrelated measure of volatility. My code is based on code that can be found here:["Multivariate Garch implementation"](http://unstarched.net/2013/01/03/the-garch-dcc-model-and-2-stage-dccmvt-estimation/). I highly recommend reading this.

Load all your series as before

```
library(rmgarch)
library(parallel)
library(quantmod)
```

Ensure equal length of your data and calculate log returns of the time series

```
Dat<-data.frame(GDAXI.DE[-c(1:22)],GSPC,CRSOX,EEM)
Dat<-apply(Dat,2,function(x) Delt(x,k=1,type="log"))
```

Specify your univariate garch process along with your multivariate model. Here I include both the vanilla DCC-GARCH as well as the assymmetric DCC-GARCH model specification

```
xspec = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1, 1)), variance.model = list(garchOrder = c(1,1), model = 'sGARCH'), distribution.model = 'norm')
uspec = multispec(replicate(4, xspec))
spec1 = dccspec(uspec = uspec, dccOrder = c(1, 1), distribution = 'mvnorm')
spec1a = dccspec(uspec = uspec, dccOrder = c(1, 1), model='aDCC', distribution = 'mvnorm')
```

When performing computationally intense models, I recommend using a parallel approach. Luckily `rmgarch` has this feature build in. So, lets open the number of clusters we want to perform the analysis on

```
cl = makePSOCKcluster(4)
multf = multifit(uspec, Dat, cluster = cl)
```

We can now finally fit the model

```
fit1 = dccfit(spec1, data = Dat, fit.control = list(eval.se = TRUE), fit = multf, cluster = cl)
fit_adcc = dccfit(spec1, data = Dat, fit.control = list(eval.se = TRUE), fit = multf, cluster = cl)
print(fit1)           
print(fit_adcc)
```

It is important to remember to close your clusters using

```
stopCluster(cl)
```

I hope this helps you in what you are looking for!

Comment: thanks, your answer is helping me. I'm actually try to just have an Garch(1,1) Model and then I want to achieve a VECH and a BEKK model and compare the 3 on a certain forecast horizon.

Comment: Then have a look at the `MTS` package for Vech and BEKK estimation methods. I must admit, I have used the package for estimation of a BEKK model and they do take long to estimate, so take that into account. From a theoretical standpoint, do not run a BEKK model larger than 3 variables interacting. The parameters that needs to be estimated becomes unstable in larger systems.

Comment: thanks, my BEKK is working. Do you now a package to use for the vec model? I already tried library(rmgarch), library(fGarch), library(ccgarch),
library(mgarch). But I couldn't find a something helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not seen a package to implement that model. As a last resort I would go and have a look at the source code for the `BEKK11` function on [github](https://github.com/cran/MTS/blob/master/R/MVM.R). You might be able to code the `VECH` formulation yourself by knowing how the `BEKK11` was coded